# Joomla! - Registration not working

Tags: authentication, joomla, localhost, registration

I'm running Joomla! 1.5.22 on localhost.

For the website's registration, after the user fills in all the information and click on 'send registration', the page simply 'refresh' only.

So i tried to log in with the new user's username and password but it only 'refresh' the page and the user isn't logged in.

May i know what is the problem?

Sorry as i'm a beginner in Joomla!

Comment: Which extension are you using for Registration?

Comment: The one which comes along with Joomla

Answer (score 0):

as you said that you are trying to create a user on your local host first check the followings by default settings in your joomla administrator pannel cause as i see in joomla 1.5.22 version if you will create a user then you should have to verify that user, in by default settings >> you will found the settings at :

1. login at admin pannel
2. click on site menu and choose > global configuration.
3. click on the system tab

then you will found the user settings: set `No` in the new user account activation and then register and try to login,,

**IMP:** if you will try this setting on real server then suggest you set `Yes` option on the new user account activation..